# Remember a file upload on form submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and jquery to create a form that takes text values and a single file upload.
I want it so that if the form validation fails, the uploaded image is still visible to the user, but I'm at a loss now about how to do this without issues popping up.

My current solution is uploading the image regardless if the form validated or not, and then checking if a file with the same name as the name in $_FILES exists, and serving that. But this leads me to a problem with duplicates. I'm appending duplicate file name with a number (eg. file2.jpg), but that means the file uploaded will always find the image name "file.jpg" even if the file the user uploaded with allocated the name "file3.jpg".

There must be a simpler way.

Comment: _“checking if a file with the same name as the name in $_FILES exists, and serving that”_ – that does not make any sense. If a file `foo.jpg` already exists in the destination folder, and the user uploaded a file with the name `foo.jpg`, that does not have to mean they are actually the same image, not at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand, which is what I'm saying is a problem my current solution has.

Answer (score 0):

How about save file with hashed name md5(name+actualTimestamp) and save this file name to user session (you could save this filename in cookies or use session mysql table with serialized session data).

Comment: Glad to help ;) (btw you can mark this answer as helpful to help others with same question ;) )

Answer (score 0):

How about you assign a unique id to the form, probably a combination of year, month, day, hour, minute and seconds then move uploaded image to a temp directory on your server, save the image with the same name as the form id....

your code should be something like:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">

<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['form_id'])){ echo $_POST['form_id']; }else{ echo date("Ymdhis"); }" />

<!-- other form objects goes here -->

</form>
```